# Android Studio Layout Editor: How do I center these views in the middle of this Layout

Tags: android-relativelayout

In the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Mm8.jpg), you can see I've drawn in red arrows indicating that I want to shift the widgets to the right a bit. In other words, I want to center things, and yet I'm having difficulty.

Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            >
    </DatePicker>
    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker" android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </TimePicker>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/timePicker"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to all he widgets you want to center horizontally.
Also I suggest you change the `linearLayout1`'s width and height to `match_parent`. `fill_parent`, which is value of `layout_height` is deprecated long time ago, and in order to center your widgets horizontally on the screen, you need your layout to match the screen bounds.